# PrimeFaces gmap change default view

Tags: google-maps, jsf, primefaces

I am new using primefaces gmap control. Im try to change the default view (satellite) to map view. But it always render on satellite view. I can change this view using mapTypeControl buttons, but I want change this before control display to the user.
My control looks like:

```
<p:gmap   center="#{mapBean.center}" zoom="15" type="hybrid" style="width:100%;height:15em" model="#    {mapBean.model}" widgetVar="M1" />`
```

and my bean:

```
public class MapBackingBean {
private MapModel model = new DefaultMapModel();
private String center="8.989701,-79.516168";
  /**
 * Creates a new instance of MapBackingBean
 */
public MapBackingBean() {
    model.addOverlay(new Marker(new LatLng(8.989701,-79.516168), "Regency Tower"));
}
//getters and setters
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<p:gmap   center="#{mapBean.center}" zoom="15" type="ROADMAP" style="width:100%;height:15em" model="#    {mapBean.model}" widgetVar="M1" />
```

Change the type from hybrid (satellite view) to ROADMAP?
(possibly requires lowercase)